# How can I change the default project in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, project

Every time I start `PyCharm Community Edition` it automatically opens a project in the `PyCharmProjects` directory. There are several projects in that directory. I would like to have another project open automatically. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Pycharm Preferences, Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings, and there will be a Startup/Shutdown section. It doesn't look like you can specify a particular project, but you can stop it from reopening the last project on startup (which is what seems to be happening for you now), and select from a list instead.

Comment: More info here if you need it! https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/system-settings.html